# Downloading files using wget

Tags: wget

I am trying to download files from [this website](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE48191).

The URL is: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/download/?acc=GSE48191&format=file

When I use this command:

```
wget http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/download/?acc=GSE48191&format=file
```

I get only `index.html?acc=GSE48191` which is some kind of binary format.

How can I download the files from this HTTP site?

Answer (score 27):

I think your `?` gets interpreted by shell (Correction by vinc17: more likely, it's the `&` which gets interpreted).

Just try with simple quotes around your URL:

```
wget 'http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/download/?acc=GSE48191&format=file'
```

Note that the file you are requesting is a `.tar` file but the above command will save it as `index.html?acc=GSE48191&format=file`. To have it correctly named, you can either rename it to `.tar`:

```
mv 'index.html?acc=GSE48191&format=file' GSE4819.tar
```

Or you can give the name as an option to `wget`:

```
wget -O GSE48191.tar 'http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/download/?acc=GSE48191&format=file'
```

The above command will save the downloaded file as `GSE48191.tar` directly.

Comment: It gets downloaded but it is not even a directory. If you look at the link http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE48191 , you can see there are multiple .gz files. I still can't access them??

Comment: I suppose that the OP uses a shell that ignores `?` as a wildcard since nothing matches. The main problem is `&`: this will run the part that precedes (thus with an incomplete URL) in the background. But the solution is the same: to quote the URL.

Comment: Thanks to you terdon and vinc for edit/corrections. @user3138373: I can't find your .gz files on provided links, could you please tell again what URL you use to see/access them?

Comment: @user3138373 the file you download is an archive (`.tar` file) that contains the .gz files. Once you have downloaded it, run `tar xvf GSE4819.tar` to expand the archive and access the files.

Answer (score 3):

Another way that might possibly work is by using this command:

`wget -O nameOfTar.tar "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/download/?acc=GSE48191&format=file"`

The `-O` command will specify the name to download to.

Of course, your initial problem is because the "&" was being interpreted by the shell, surrounding the URL with double quotes fixes the issue.

Comment: `-O` **option** is used to specify the name of the file in which dowloaded data is saved. It has no incidence on downloaded data (maybe that's what you meant, but I found it unclear).

Comment: Yes sorry, I will make my correction

Comment: I'm not sure why this got downvoted.

Comment: I did not downvote, but that's probably because your solution does not fix problem: `&` is interpreted by shell, and download of `.tar` file will fail.

Answer (score 1):

None of these answers worked for me.

However, you can find GSE* folders within the NCBI ftp page:

```
ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/series/GSE48nnn/GSE48191/suppl/
```

You can then copy the link address from that file and just do a simple wget:

```
wget ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/series/GSE48nnn/GSE48191/suppl/GSE48191_RAW.tar
```

Answer (score 0):

> wget -O "name-you-want-to-save-as.format" http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/download/?acc=GSE48191&format=file

That should get you the file you want to download to the current directory you are in.

Comment: `wget: missing URL` is what `wget` replies to that, because you are missing the argument to `-O`. Also, I think this probably doesn't solve the OP's problem anyway.

Comment: Because the URL contains `&`, this answer doesn't work unless you add `""` or `''` around the URL.

Answer (score 0):

From $ curl -G http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/download/?acc=GSE48191

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/download/?acc=GSE48191">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

So you need to do

```
wget https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/download/?acc=GSE48191
```

Notice the "s" after http. I tried it myself and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

What would help better is giving the page you got the link from which is:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/download/?acc=GSE48191

Now with that page the clickable link is:
https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/series/GSE48nnn/GSE48191/suppl/GSE48191_RAW.tar

So use wget with the link is:
`wget https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/series/GSE48nnn/GSE48191/suppl/GSE48191_RAW.tar`