# downloading a file behind a link

Tags: wget

I want to write a script to download the WEbStorm IDE from Jetbrains and then do further stuffs. But I am unable to download the tar ball.

I am following this, but it doesnt solve my problem. 
[downloading files using wget](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145946/downloading-files-using-wget)

The webpage where I want to download the file from is https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/download/download-thanks.html?platform=linux

It looks like it is quite simple, but I just get a plain html page all the time when I do a wget. Doing it over the browser address bar or addons like DownThemAll  is completely fine.

Following is my command

```
wget 'https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/download/download-thanks.html?platform=linux' -O WebStorm.tar.gz
```

I can download the file from here:

```
wget https://download.jetbrains.com/webstorm/WebStorm-2017.2.4.tar.gz
```

but I could only find this URL after a little bit of digging. Is there a way to simply get the download file url by parsing the Download button?

Is it also possible to do via curl?

Comment: "A bit of digging" means "reading the text on the download page"?

Comment: @Kusalananda  No, a bit of digging means, using the firefox addon DownThemAll. It displays where the file is "actually" been downloaded from.

Answer (score 1):

This link should work for latest Linux version of WebStorm:
https://data.services.jetbrains.com/products/download?code=WS&platform=linux

You can get this address by calling page you wanted to get in a first place and searching for direct link:

```
      $ curl 'https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/download/download-thanks.html?platform=linux' | grep "direct link"
      <p class="sub-title no-margin-bottom">Your download should start shortly. If it doesn't, please use the <a id="download-link" href="//data.services.jetbrains.com/products/download?code=WS" data-release-download-link="">direct link</a>.</p>
```

Just add &platfor=your_platform and you get latest version

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a short script that will install any Linux-compatible JetBrains IDE, including WebStorm. You can find more details [here](http://breandan.net/2014/08/18/shell-script/).

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Installing IntelliJ IDEA..."

# We need root to install
[ $(id -u) != "0" ] && exec sudo "$0" "$@"

# Attempt to install a JDK
# apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
# add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java && apt-get update && apt-get install oracle-java8-installer

# Prompt for edition
while true; do
    read -p "Enter 'U' for Ultimate or 'C' for Community: " ed 
    case $ed in
        [Uu]* ) ed=U; break;;
        [Cc]* ) ed=C; break;;
    esac
done

# Fetch the most recent version
VERSION=$(wget "https://www.jetbrains.com/intellij-repository/releases" -qO- | grep -P -o -m 1 "(?<=https://www.jetbrains.com/intellij-repository/releases/com/jetbrains/intellij/idea/BUILD/)[^/]+(?=/)")

# Prepend base URL for download
URL="https://download.jetbrains.com/idea/ideaI$ed-$VERSION.tar.gz"

echo $URL

# Truncate filename
FILE=$(basename ${URL})

# Set download directory
DEST=~/Downloads/$FILE

echo "Downloading idea-I$ed-$VERSION to $DEST..."

# Download binary
wget -cO ${DEST} ${URL} --read-timeout=5 --tries=0

echo "Download complete!"

# Set directory name
DIR="/opt/idea-I$ed-$VERSION"

echo "Installing to $DIR"

# Untar file
if mkdir ${DIR}; then
    tar -xzf ${DEST} -C ${DIR} --strip-components=1
fi

# Grab executable folder
BIN="$DIR/bin"

# Add permissions to install directory
chmod -R +rwx ${DIR}

# Set desktop shortcut path
DESK=/usr/share/applications/IDEA.desktop

# Add desktop shortcut
echo "[Desktop Entry]\nEncoding=UTF-8\nName=IntelliJ IDEA\nComment=IntelliJ IDEA\nExec=${BIN}/idea.sh\nIcon=${BIN}/idea.png\nTerminal=false\nStartupNotify=true\nType=Application" -e > ${DESK}

# Create symlink entry
ln -sf ${BIN}/idea.sh /usr/local/bin/idea

echo "Done."
```

Comment: The question is about how to download a file, specifically a `.tar.gz` file, given only the URL of the HTML web page from which it can be downloaded. Your answer assumes that the user already knows the URL of the `.tar.gz` file; the OP already knows how to download a file given its specific URL. And then your script does a lot of things that the question doesn’t ask for, which is OK, as long as you answer the question. Also, you should use more quotes.

Comment: The question is not specific, but I tried to solve the problem @infoclogged encountered, which involves downloading the WebStorm IDE using wget. I suspect OP is not interested in the details of `wget`. However even if there was a broader question here, I would note that the other answer also has the same issue (doesn't even mention `wget`). `Also, you should use more quotes.` Where should I use more quotes? Thanks!

Comment: Where should I use more quotes? `"$(id -u)"`, `case "$ed" in`, optionally `VERSION="$(…)"` (it’s OK that there are quoted strings between the parentheses), `FILE=$(basename "$URL")` (or, optionally, `FILE="$(basename "$URL")"`, `wget -cO "$DEST" "$URL" …`, `mkdir "$DIR"`, `chmod -R +rwx "$DIR"`, ``echo "…" -e > "$DESK"``, and ``ln -sf "$BIN/idea.sh" /usr/local/bin/idea``. And maybe a couple of others; that was a quick scan. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … References: [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/80216), [Security implications of failing to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/80216), [`${variable_name}` doesn’t mean what you think it does …](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32210/80216#286525) and [Bash quotes unescaped on command substitution](https://superuser.com/q/909764/354511).